# cant see the images on my website

Tags: php, html, image, png, hosting

i recently started learning php, and i didnt have much experience with html and css too, so i decided to create a website just to practice. i created a simple one with couple of days and wanted to test it on a free web hosting site. So used 000webhost, i uploaded my files as they appeared on my computer, with the same exact directories. but the problem is my website doesnt open the pictures. it shows the pictures when i open it directly from my computer but doesnt show them when i open it from internet. here is an example of a html code:

```
<img  src="imgs/header.png" />
```

and my website [slapswithfriends.host22.com](http://slapswithfriends.host22.com/)

Comment: @Joren "So used 000webhost,"

Comment: The images are broken try uploading them again

Comment: Have you tried using some other pictures, for example downloaded and reuploaded from the internet?

Comment: it is located on a webserver, and wait ill try uploading again :)

Comment: yes i guess images were broken it works now :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that your pictures were corrupted during the upload. Try to upload them again. Maybe use a different upload method. i don't know about  000webhost but usually these hosts provide some sort of ftp access got upload.

Answer (score 1):

if you are using 000webhost just try this,it may help you.
first go to this http://imgur.com/ and create a account and upload the image you want add on your website,after its uploaded successfully copy the link of that image and paste it in .

Answer (score 0):

When you open an image [directly](http://slapswithfriends.host22.com/imgs/01.png) you can see that they are there but can not be opened.

Make sure your webhost supports image hosting. If not, you can upload your images to an external image hoster (e.g. [Imgur](http://imgur.com/)).

If your webhost supports images, the images didn't get uploaded correctly. Try reuploading them.

Answer (score 0):

Check your server's folder accessibility. users must be able to read that folder's content.
use: sudo chmod 644 folder_name;

Answer (score 0):

Try with different slashes. On my localhost it was like "\assets\img\example", but on webhost this type doesnt show me results. Finnaly I tried with standard slash,and it woks "assets/img/exemple". It's maybe based on WEB Virtual OS and their configurations about paths.